# Finding solutions to $ \sin\left(n \pi \frac{T_p}{T}\right) - \sin\left(n \pi \frac{T_0}{T}\right) = \sin\left( \frac{{n \pi}}{2}\right) $

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm trying to figure out how I can find a solution(s) to the equation below.

$$
\sin\left(n \pi \frac{T_p}{T}\right) - \sin\left(n \pi  \frac{T_0}{T}\right)  = \sin\left(  \frac{{n \pi}}{2}\right) 
$$

I'm expecting something in the form of $T_p$ and $T_o$ expressed as part of $T$, for example: $T_p = \frac12 T$ and $T_0 = \frac13 T$.

Any hits would be hugely appreciated.

Best,
A

Comment: Solve for $T$ ?

Comment: $T_p = \frac{1}{2}T$, $T_0 =0T$ by inspection